# How to use a string "mean" or "sum" in groupby to make dynamic?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dictionary:

```
dict = { "A": ("a", "mean"),
         "B": ("b", "sum")}
```

I want to use the following function for each of the keys:

```
for i in dict.keys():
    df.groupby(i)[dict[i][0]].sum()
or
    df.groupby(i)[dict[i][0]].mean()
```

How can I replace hardcoded "sum" or "mean", so it uses what is given in the dictionary?
Something like this:

```
df.groupby(i)[dict[i][0]].dict[i][1]()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they are just strings `sum`, `mean`, which are valid Pandas function names, you can pass them as is with `agg` or `apply`. Also, you can rewrite your code so it can be a bit more readable:

```
# Please please do not use `dict` as a variable
for k, (col,op) in your_dict.items(): 
    df.groupby(k)[col].agg(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

`agg` ([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)) function is appropriate for this. An example for the use:

```py
my_dict = { "A": ("a", "mean"),
         "B": ("b", "sum")}

for (col_for_group, (col_for_agg, agg_func)) in my_dict.items():
    df.groupby(col_for_group)[col_for_agg].agg(agg_func)
```

The use of reserved name like `dict` (datatype) as variable name is not recommended!